# how to read data from csv as date format in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, to-date

I have data in following format

```
Month        Country BA Total
11/1/2018     CN     3   10
```

after reading Month comes as object though I want in date format,
I tried to convert it in date time format using

```
hs = pd.read_csv('history.csv',parse_dates=['Month'])  #this is not solving the issue either

hs['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(hs['Month']) #this throws error
```

Please suggest me how to read it as date or convert it to date format

Comment: could you please add the error output (traceback)? also, "11/1/2018" means mm/dd/yyyy? or is it day first?

Comment: error: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-04-19 00:00:00           it is mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: hm "1-04-19" looks like a different format; does your "Month" column contain date/time strings with mixed formats? In principle, `pd.to_datetime` has no issues with parsing mm/dd/yyyy to datetime correctly. You can set `errors='coerce'` to skip the errors, but that will leave "NaT" for those elements in the datetime column.

Comment: yes I noticed that last few rows had different format, I have updated it and ran again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')

df = pd.read_csv('history.csv', parse_dates=['Month'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Comment: from datetime import datetime
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')
#hs = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\kumaashi\Documents\Treasury\prophet\history.csv',parse_dates=['Month'])
hs = pd.read_csv('history.csv',parse_dates=['Month'], date_parser=dateparse)

Answer (score 2):

try one of this two line, maybe don't get error, your error maybe base on **day is first or month is first**:

```
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
# or
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], dayfirst=False)
```

OR

```
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], format='%d/%m/%y')
# or
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the timespan that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years
Workaround:

This will force the dates which are outside the bounds to NaT

`pd.to_datetime(date_col_to_force, errors = 'coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

If the dates in the file are less than pristine, it is often a good idea to load the file without `parse_dates`, then use `pd.to_datetime()` which has better control, including format and how to deal with errors (`'raise'`, `'coerce'`, or `'ignore'`).

Answer (score -1):

thanks a lot to all of the suggestions, I tried last one and it worked, as I am running short of time, could not try other suggestions, will definitely try once I get time.